# Split the String, If it exceeds the specified length

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I am generating a XML format file using String Builder. the file will look something like this :-

```
  StringBuilder strBldr = new StringBuilder();
  strBldr.AppendLine("<Root>");
  strBldr.AppendLine("<ProductDetails>");
  strBldr.AppendLine("<PId>" + lblproductid.Text + "</PId>");
  strBldr.AppendLine("<PDesc>" + strtxtProductDesc + "</PDesc>");
  strBldr.AppendLine("</ProductDetails>");
  strBldr.AppendLine("</Root>");
```

This is in for loop, so it may contain many product details.
Now I need to split this string if it exceeds the limited length suppose 100. 
Till now it was easy. I am able to  split this using following method:-

```
 public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(this string str, int maxLength)
 {
        for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; index += maxLength)
        {
            yield return str.Substring(index, Math.Min(maxLength, str.Length - index));
        }
  }
```

But the thing is, this method just simply splits the string if it finds length is greater that 100. but I need to be sure if it tries to split from middle of the xml node, then it should find the just above `<ProductDetails>` node and split from there.
what should I add to the code to achieve this?

Comment: That sounds rather hacky, what is the overall goal here? Are you trying to return a collection of XML nodes? Because there are better ways to do that...

Comment: What happens if the contents of a single node is more than 100 characters long?

Comment: Never ever build xml as a string. Use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx). Don't randomly remove content from an xml document. Fix whatever consumer can't handle > 100 characters.

Comment: @DGibbs : thanks for the response. Actually here I want to store that string(with xml format) in database table, so if it exceeds the limited length(suppose 5000), and if that length comes between any child node then it should split from "<ProductDetails> " tag and should insert in next row.

Comment: @RajeshBiswas Are you imposing a character limit on the column for `ProductDetails` e.g. `varchar(5000)`? If so, you could just limit the user input to a specific number of characters (minus the XML) on the front end to prevent this situation from even occurring, thus solving your problem. varchar max can store up to 8000 bytes/chars...

Comment: @RajeshBiswas: Is there any reason you don't store the entire XML in the database as a `varchar(max)` column, which can store up to 2GB?

Comment: @mellamokb : I need to store this in one row only. if it exceeds the limit then rest of the product details should go to other row.

Comment: @All: Thank you very much to you all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You definitely should use `XDocument` instead of `string` to construct and query XML data.**

You could create an extension method on `XDocument` class that will split by length:

```
public static class XDocumentExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(this XDocument source, string elementName, int maxLength)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(elementName))
            throw new ArgumentException("elementName cannot be null or empty.", "elementName");
        if (maxLength <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("maxLength has to be greater than 0.", "maxLength");

        return SplitByLengthImpl(source, elementName, maxLength);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLengthImpl(XDocument source, string elementName, int maxLength)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var element in source.Root.Elements(elementName))
        {
            var currentElementString = element.ToString();
            if (builder.Length + currentElementString.Length > maxLength)
            {
                if (builder.Length > 0)
                {
                    yield return builder.ToString();
                    builder.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(
                        "source document contains element with length greater than maxLength", "source");
                }
            }

            builder.AppendLine(currentElementString);
        }
        if (builder.Length > 0)
            yield return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

And then use it like that:

```
var parts = doc.SplitByLength("ProductDetails", 200).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

How about if `lblproductid.Text` contains, for ex, `&`, `<` or `>`?

Therefore I would use a real xml parser instead of forming it by hand.

```
var xElem = new XElement("Root",
                    new XElement("ProductDetails",
                        new XElement("PId", lblproductid.Text),
                        new XElement("PDesc",strtxtProductDesc)));

var xml = xElem.ToString();
```

output would be:

```
<Root>
  <ProductDetails>
    <PId>aaa</PId>
    <PDesc>aaa</PDesc>
  </ProductDetails>
</Root>
```

PS: You can loop for `ProductDetails` and count the total length.